# How can I check if user DIDN'T click on any UI Elements? If he missed the click and simply clicked on the background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I modify some button's colors that I want to reset when the user clicks outside any of the buttons from the grid, but still clicks somewhere in the UserControl. I tried to add a MouseDown event to the background of the grid but it it not a valid event.
Something like this

```
<Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush
            Mouse.MouseDown="ImageBrush_MouseDown"
            ImageSource="/Res/maptest3.png"
            Stretch="None"
            />
 </Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
**x:Name="windowClicked"**  //Add this to the **xaml** file

In the source code:

```
private void windowClicked_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // or your what you want to do
        MessageBox.Show("Background Clicked"); 
    }
```